# Benefit of using the newer Laravel Mix over Elixir

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir, laravel-mix

Since Laravel 5.4, the default method to compile assets is using Laravel Mix, instead of elixir.

I know that "Mix" uses WebPack by default to compile the assets.

What benefits does this method bring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Mix also allows you to compile without WebPack, and this always
>   produces files that are smaller in size and work the same.

This is entirely incorrect. Have you attempted to configure any of the myriad options to optimize your bundle at all?

Start with the [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) plugin. This will give you an idea where your bloat is, what is duplicated, and where to start trimming your application.

Between uglifying, chunking, deduplification, minification, etc. you'll have in the end compiled resources that are far from "large".

Now I'll grant you it has a steep learning curve comparative to other tools, regardless, WebPack is an incredibly powerful tool, you need to take the time to learn it's configuration capabilities.

Care to elaborate on what you mean by working the same? I run several production applications as well as a number of smaller personal projects. I never seem to get different results after each build.

But in the end it's just a tool. A tool like any other tool, you use what you feel comfortable with and what fits for the job. There's a reason it as selected as the default, though. And it isn't because the maintainers are ignorant by any means.

Comment: Working the same means that the resulting JS file operates the same in the end user's browser. I didn't expect it to work differently, I guess I was just stating the obvious. I didn't mean to sound like I thought the maintainers are ignorant (I love how actively maintained Laravel is!), just trying to understand the move toward WebPack. Maybe it would be more obvious if the project I'm working on was more than 300 kb of JS (probably with nearly zero bloat). Thanks for the tips though, I'll check out that analyzer.

Comment: I'm still a little lost on how the js operates differently. What libraries, if any, are you using? Are you writing es6 JavaScript? There is a whole slew of transpiler and syntax normalizer out there to standardize the code so it works on all browsers. I use babel it some way or another in all my projects. https://babeljs.io/. When you get up to several MBs of js dependencies, then you're really see the difference.

Comment: I never said the JS operates differently....? I think you may have mis-read that part. Thanks for your time, though, that analyzing tool is pretty cool :D

Comment: `Working the same means that the resulting JS file operates the same in the end user's browser` first sentence in your comment. Anyhow, all good, the analyzer is quite useful ;)